# Matlab getting blood vessels only in image

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

I am trying to get get an image of the retina (image 1, below), to show only the blood vessels in black and white (image 2, below) by using the functions which are avaible in the image processing toolbox, thresholding, morphological operations,etc. I have tried the following, however it does not get the result I need:

```
% READ IMAGES 
eye1 = imread('Retina1.png');
%display coloured version(original)
imshow(eye1);

% convert to grayscale
grayeye1 =rgb2gray(eye1);

% display grayscale
imshow(grayeye1);
    
% make darker
dgrayeye1 = imadjust(grayeye1,[0.1 0.9],[]);
imshow(a);
    
se = strel('disk',1);
    
cannyeye = edge(dgrayeye1,'canny',0.15);
figure,imshow(cannyeye);
    
dilate = imdilate(cannyeye,se);
figure, imshow(dilate)
```

image 1:

[image]

image 2:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

This is not an easy task. There are several reference papers that you may need to investigate in:

1. [Retinal vessel extraction by matched ﬁlter with ﬁrst-order derivative of Gaussian](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/uploaded_files/5670/Zhang.pdf). And the Matlab code is included in this [post](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/105145).
2. [An Automatic Hybrid Method for Retinal Blood Vessel Extraction](http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/amc/amc18/amc18313.pdf). It uses morphological approach with openings/closings and the top-hat transform. The fuzzy clustering is applied after the that.
3. The most common used vessel detection method is from the paper [Hessian-based Multiscale Vessel Enhancement Filtering](http://www.dtic.upf.edu/~afrangi/articles/miccai1998.pdf) by Frangi et al. There is a Matlab implementation, [FrangiFilter2D](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/24409-hessian-based-frangi-vesselness-filter/content/FrangiFilter2D.m), that works on 2D vessel images.

I tried this code in your case, hopefully you can start from here...

```
options=struct('FrangiScaleRange', [1 5], 'FrangiScaleRatio', 1, 'FrangiBetaOne', 1,...
        'FrangiBetaTwo', 7.5, 'verbose',true,'BlackWhite',true);
[outIm,whatScale,Direction] = FrangiFilter2D(double(dgrayeye1), options);
imshow(outIm)
```

Image:

[image]

Comment: how would then i remove the outer line ( the large circle outside)?

Comment: Thank you user2058776. I didn't try, but you can use imfindcircles (http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/examples/detect-and-measure-circular-objects-in-an-image.html), or regionprops to detect the circle along with the radius, and set the region outside the radius zero

Comment: or much easier, you can create a circle mask (binary) with some thresholding method, shrink the radius a little bit, then set the values outside the mask all zeros

Comment: Can someone explain the meaning and practical use of every parameter specified in the options structure ? @lennon310